# Create JSON without backslash

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I'm sending JSON to my backend and saving it in my database, but in my JSON data, I have some `\` characters. How can I save my JSON without those backslashes?

```
 survey.onComplete.add(function(result) {
   try {

     const response = ResultService.saveSurveyResult({
       result: (document.querySelector("#surveyResult").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result.data)),
       UserId: UserId,
       SurveyId: 1
     });
```

This is my JSON I save in the database:

```
"{\"customerName\":\"jhkghjgh\",\"birthdate\":\"05.06.1990\"}"
```

This is what I want to save:

```
{"customerName":"jhkghjgh","birthdate":"05.06.1990"}
```

This is my backend code:

```
async saveSurveyResult (req, res) {
  try {
    const surveyResult = await SurveyResult.create(req.body)

    const surveyResultJson = surveyResult.toJSON()

    res.send({
      surveyResult: surveyResultJson
    })
```

Comment: What does req.body contain?

Comment: the req.body contains the result of a Survey (result: (document.querySelector("#surveyResult").innerHTML =
      JSON.stringify(result.data)),
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just deleted the part where i create a String. So this works fine:

```
 try {

    const response = ResultService.saveSurveyResult({
      result: result.data,
      UserId: UserId,
      SurveyId: 1
    });
```